# How to set a list<Class> in a Class (Java)

Tags: java, class, arraylist

I have the Pipe class:

```
    public class Pipe {
        private int length;

        public Pipe(int length) {
            this.length = length;
        }
        // plus getter and setter
    }
```

Then the PipeGenerator class:

```
public class PipeGenerator  {
    private List<Pipe> pipeList;

    public PipeGenerator(int numberOfPipes) {
        List<Integer> availableTypes = generateAvailableTypes();
        List<Pipe> pipes = createRandomPipesList(numberOfPipes, availableTypes);

        this.pipeList.set(pipes);
        // plus getter and setter
    }
}
```

My code is highlighed with red in Intellij and I dont understand why. Here is a picture:

[image]

The createRandomPipesList method:

```
private List<Pipe> createRandomPipesList(int numberOfPipes, List<Integer> availableTypes) {
    List<Pipe> pipes = new ArrayList<Pipe>();
    addPipesToList(numberOfPipes, availableTypes, pipes);
    return pipes;
}
```

So basically I want to generate a List and set it to the pipeList private property in the PipeGenerator class. What will be the way to do it?

Comment: `pipeList = createRandomPipeList(...)` why not like this?

Comment: list.set is not for setting a collection but an individual element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The set method of the List class is not doing what you think it is.  Refer to the API http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#set-int-E-.

Instead just assign the new list.

```
pipeList = pipes;
```

Answer (score 1):

Right now you are adding pipes which is an array of type Pipes to an array of type Pipes. So you are adding an array to an array of type Pipes. Compare this to adding an integer to an array of type float, it doesnt work.

I think you want to add pipes.get(index) to pipelist.

```
for(int i = 0; i < numberOfPipes.size(); i++){
    this.pipeList.set(i,pipes.get(i));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Find out the [List#set](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/List.java#List.set%28int%2Cjava.lang.Object%29) method. It takes 2 parameter. First integer one is need for at which index you are going to set the Object that is pass as the second parameter.